# Amazon Linux で Nginx を起動するとエラー: Address already in use

Tags: nginx, amazon-linux

Amazon ELBにつないでいる、EC2(Amazon Linux)にNginxをインストールして起動するとエラーが出ます。

用途として、Apacheを起動したままで、Kibana用にNginxを使いたいです。
EC2,ELB環境にNginxをインストールして起動したのですが、以下の通りエラーが出てきます。

**設定ファイルを編集:**

```
$ sudo vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf

server {
  listen                *:10080 ;

  server_name           localhost;
  access_log            /var/log/nginx/kibana.access.log;

  location /kibana/ {
    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html  index.htm;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
  }
}
```

**nginx サービスを起動:**

```
$ sudo service nginx start

Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

---

`lsof` コマンドでポートの使用状況を調べると以下の通りですが、Nginxが使われておらず、どれを`kill`したらいいのかわからないです。
httpdを止めて、nginxを起動すると成功するんですが、ELBでout of service になってしまいます。

```
$ sudo lsof -i:80

COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   2456   root    4u  IPv6  10447      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2535 apache    4u  IPv6  10447      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2536 apache    4u  IPv6  10447      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2536 apache    9u  IPv6  13343      0t0  TCP ip-111-11-11-111.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:http->ip-111-11-11-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:54275 (ESTABLISHED)
httpd   2537 apache    4u  IPv6  10447      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2538 apache    4u  IPv6  10447      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2538 apache    9u  IPv6  13342      0t0  TCP ip-111-11-11-111.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:http->ip-222-22-22-222.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:39934 (ESTABLISHED)
httpd   2539 apache    4u  IPv6  10447      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2588 apache    4u  IPv6  10447      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2589 apache    4u  IPv6  10447      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2590 apache    4u  IPv6  10447      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2701 apache    4u  IPv6  10447      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apacheが動いていますね。
Amazon Linux or CentOS であれば `sudo service httpd stop` で apache を停止してみてください。
また、 `sudo chkconfig httpd off` で apache の自動起動を無効化してください。